Firebase functions/Nodemailer sending email to myself when a form is submited
I want to use firebase functions with nodemailer to receive emails when a contact form is submited. The form is being saved in my database and then i want to use it in my index.js file with a function that triggers when a new entry is registered. The following code is what i have and it appears that functions.firestore.document is not treated as a function.
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

admin.initializeApp();

const gmailEmail = functions.config().gmail.email;
const gmailPassword = functions.config().gmail.password;

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: gmailEmail,
    pass: gmailPassword,
  },
});

const contactFormPath = "contactSubmissions/{docId}";

exports.sendContactEmail = functions.firestore
.document(contactFormPath)
  .onCreate(async (snap) => {
    const data = snap.data();

    const mailOptions = {
      from: gmailEmail,
      to: gmailEmail,
      subject: `New Contact Form Submission: ${data.subject}`,
      text: `
        You have a new contact form submission!
        
        Name: ${data.firstName} ${data.lastName}
        Email: ${data.email}
        Subject: ${data.subject}
        Message: ${data.message}
      `,
    };

    try {
      await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
      console.log("Email sent successfully");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error sending email:", error);
    }
  });


=== Deploying to 'imidea-940fa'...

i  deploying functions
i  functions: preparing codebase functions for deployment
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  artifactregistry: ensuring required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled...
+  artifactregistry: required API artifactregistry.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
+  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: Loading and analyzing source code for codebase functions to determine what to deploy
Serving at port 8795

TypeError: functions.firestore.document is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\WEBSITES\imidea\emails\index.js:22:2)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
    at loadModule (E:\WEBSITES\imidea\emails\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\runtime\loader.js:40:16)
    at loadStack (E:\WEBSITES\imidea\emails\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\runtime\loader.js:157:23)
    at E:\WEBSITES\imidea\emails\node_modules\firebase-functions\lib\bin\firebase-functions.js:56:56    


Error: Functions codebase could not be analyzed successfully. It may have a syntax or runtime error

Honestly tried way too many different things to remember. Installing, reinstalling different dependancies etc. Tried to reformat the code so it is not a function, however I can't seem to get it to work when I try that.

I read that there are two different generations of firebase functions here.
The functions.firestore.document is a function in v1 but not in v2 which might be the cause of the error.
Could you change the import from
const functions = require("firebase-functions");

to
const functions = require("firebase-functions/v1");

changing the import might work.
